# Why won't my footer move to the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css, web, position, footer

So I've been stuck on this issue for over a week now and it's driving me crazy. I want to position my footer at the bottom of my web page. For some reason, it just wants to float in the middle of the page, right underneath my last div. I've done a lot of research and tried a million different things, and none of them have given me the results that I need.

Here are a few of the solutions that I've tried:

- I played around with the position property, setting it to *'absolute'*, *'relative'* and *'fixed'*. *'Relative'* pushed the footer down, but also pushed the content underneath it down as well. *'Absolute'* worked in positioning it at the very bottom, but for some reason it cut the width of the footer off. (I tried manually adjusting the width back, but no luck). Same thing with *'fixed'*.
- I set the margins and padding of the *body* and *html* content to 0.
- I set the height of the body to 100%.
- I checked to make sure all tags were closed.
- I tried placing the footer outside of the body.
- I've tried creating new divs before and around the footer.

At this point, I'm not sure what the issue is. Can someone assist me?

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  background-image: url(http://michellewalling.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/purple-planet.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  max-height: 100%;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: "Lucida Console";
  
}

li {
  font-size: 150%;
  font-family: Abel;
  display: inline;
  width: 390px; 
  margin: 18px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -21px;
}


div.well {
  background-color: black;
  height: 55px;
  width: 1609px;
  position: relative;
  left: -17px;
  top: -20px; 
}

.container {
 min-height: 100%; 
}

div.main {
  background-image: url();
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -40px;
  min-height: 100%; 
}

p {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -50px;
  padding-bottom: 200px; 
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Londrina Shadow";
  font-size: 600%;
  color: black;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
}

h2 {
  font-family: Chewy;
  font-size: 300%;
  color: black;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  top: -60px;
}

li a:hover {
 background-color: gainsboro;
 color: black;
}


.links {
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 15px;  
}

.youtube {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -3px;
}

.dailymotion {
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
}


/* html, body {
 height: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0; 
}  */


.footer {
 background-color: black;
 height: 100px;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>iHeartFandomz.net</title>
  </head>
<body>

<!-- Google fonts -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Londrina Shadow" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kavivanar" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo Bhaijaan" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Acme" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Chewy" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Luckiest Guy" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "iheartfandomz.css"/>

<div class="container">
 <div class="col-xs-6">
   <div class="well"> 
   <ul>
     <li class="active"><a href="#Home" data-toggle="tab" style="text-decoration:none">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#Videos" data-toggle="tab" style="text-decoration:none">Videos</a></li>
     <li><a href="#Fanart" data-toggle="tab" style="text-decoration:none">Fanart</a></li>
   </ul>  
    </div>
     </div>

<div class="main">
  <h1>iHeartFandomz</h1>
  <h2>Fandoms Collection</h2>
 </div>

<div class="links">
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/HeartzHugzKissez" target="_blank"><img class="youtube" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/logotypes/32/youtube-512.png" style="width: 55px;"></a>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/i_Heart_fandomz" target="_blank"><img class="twitter" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/social-twitter-icon.png" style="width: 50px;"></a>
  <a href="https://gabbykun555.deviantart.com/" target="_blank"><img class="deviantart" src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/816933_9cc6964ab1b6426d818e3ea9859995f3~mv2.png" style="width: 50px;"></a>
  <a href="https://www.dailymotion.com/iHeartFandomz" target="_blank"><img class="dailymotion" src="https://www.drupal.org/files/project-images/dailymotion.png" style="width: 45px;"></a>
</div>  
</div>

<footer class="footer">
 <p>Here's the footer</p>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In addition here's some more info on CSS Tricks: [Sticky Footer, Five Ways](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. This will stick your footer at the bottom of the page. I also removed the padding of the paragraph inside of your footer.

```
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.footer p {
   padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped with pushing the footer down. But it looks like there is still spacing between the footer and bottom of page. Is there a way around that?

Comment: did you apply the code for removing the bottom padding of **p**?

Comment: I did, but changing the position from 'absolute' to 'fixed' seemed to fixed the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your css Change

```
p {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -50px;
  padding-bottom: 200px; 
}
```

to

```
p {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -50px;
  padding-bottom: 0px; 
}
```

Or you can try

```
.footer p {
  padding-bottom: 0px !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a `p` element inside your footer that has `padding-bottom: 200px;`.

You will need to remove it or change the style of the `p` that inside a `footer`.

Answer (score 0):

Working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/zrbzf22v/

Change your html like that :

```
 <footer class="footer">
        <p style="  bottom: 0px;
      padding-bottom: 0px; ">Here's the footer</p>
    </footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.footer {
   background-color: black;
   height: 100px;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   bottom: 0;
}
p {
   padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution worked perfectly. But it looks like I won't be able to change the height of the footer. Because when I try to, it creates more space between the footer and the bottom of the page. Unless there is a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

I use this and i have tested it in your project. its working

```
footer{
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        left: 0px;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this Your footer at bottom

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  background-image: url(http://michellewalling.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/purple-planet.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin:0px;
  width:100%;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: "Lucida Console";
  
}

li {
  font-size: 150%;
  font-family: Abel;
  display: inline;
  width: 390px; 
  margin: 18px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -21px;
}


div.well {
  background-color: black;
  height: 55px;
  width: 1609px;
  position: relative;
  left: -17px;
  top: -20px; 
}

.container {
 min-height: 100%; 
}

div.main {
  background-image: url();
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -40px;
  min-height: 100%; 
}

p {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -50px;
  padding-bottom: 0px; 
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Londrina Shadow";
  font-size: 600%;
  color: black;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
}

h2 {
  font-family: Chewy;
  font-size: 300%;
  color: black;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  top: -60px;
}

li a:hover {
 background-color: gainsboro;
 color: black;
}


.links {
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 15px;  
}

.youtube {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -3px;
}

.dailymotion {
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
}


/* html, body {
 height: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0; 
}  */


.footer {
 background-color: black;
 height: 100px;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>iHeartFandomz.net</title>
  </head>
<body>

<!-- Google fonts -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Londrina Shadow" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kavivanar" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo Bhaijaan" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Acme" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Chewy" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Luckiest Guy" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "iheartfandomz.css"/>

<div class="container">
 <div class="col-xs-6">
   <div class="well"> 
   <ul>
     <li class="active"><a href="#Home" data-toggle="tab" style="text-decoration:none">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#Videos" data-toggle="tab" style="text-decoration:none">Videos</a></li>
     <li><a href="#Fanart" data-toggle="tab" style="text-decoration:none">Fanart</a></li>
   </ul>  
    </div>
     </div>

<div class="main">
  <h1>iHeartFandomz</h1>
  <h2>Fandoms Collection</h2>
 </div>

<div class="links">
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/HeartzHugzKissez" target="_blank"><img class="youtube" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/logotypes/32/youtube-512.png" style="width: 55px;"></a>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/i_Heart_fandomz" target="_blank"><img class="twitter" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/social-twitter-icon.png" style="width: 50px;"></a>
  <a href="https://gabbykun555.deviantart.com/" target="_blank"><img class="deviantart" src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/816933_9cc6964ab1b6426d818e3ea9859995f3~mv2.png" style="width: 50px;"></a>
  <a href="https://www.dailymotion.com/iHeartFandomz" target="_blank"><img class="dailymotion" src="https://www.drupal.org/files/project-images/dailymotion.png" style="width: 45px;"></a>
</div>  
</div>

<footer class="footer">
 <p>Here's the footer</p>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```